# Italicize specific words before certain characters with a string of text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 500 cell range in Excel with some cells containing text strings like the following:

"Round Circles (8): Black (4), red (2), yellow (2);
  Non Shape 9;
  Large Squares 12: Black 6, red 4, yellow 2"

The range of cells also contains other text strings but none contain a colon ":"

I need a way Italicize "Round Circles" and "Large Squares" as well as the number before the colon for each.

The numbers will vary by each cell in the range but the text will not; however, the order of the text may change such that "Round Circles" may come after "Large Squares"

"Non Shape" does not need to be italicized nor do numbers after the colon but before the next string.

The problem is the length of text string will vary due to the numbers changing from cell to cell in the range and I only want to apply this to cells in the range that contain the words "Round Circles" and "Large Squares".

I would like to write a VBA script that will italicize the specific text within a string within the range of cells.
If any one can help with this it would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Italicize()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lngPos As Integer
Dim length As Integer

For Each c In Range("L7:L500")

For i = 1 To 1000
    lngPos = InStr(c.Value, "Rate variance (" & i & "):")
    length = Len("Rate variance (" & i & "):")
    If lngPos > 0 Then
        With c.Characters(Start:=lngPos, length:=length - 1).Font
            .FontStyle = "Italic"
        End With
    End If

    lngPos = InStr(c.Value, "Prior per adj (" & i & "):")
    length = Len("Prior per adj (" & i & "):")
    If lngPos > 0 Then
        With c.Characters(Start:=lngPos, length:=length - 1).Font
            .FontStyle = "Italic"
        End With
    End If
Next i

Next c

End Sub
```

I have edited the code but the words have changed because now I working with the actual words in excel. I believe I am still missing a few components.
1.) I have not declared which sheet I am on
2.) The numbers also may contain decimals
3.) I should mention that the range I am trying to format is in fact a formula returning the text string via an Index-Match formula within excel. Would that also be a problem? If so I can change the range to actual text before it is indexed to the sheet I want it on.

To answer your questions Bobby via your response to my comment:
1. The range is updated
2. The range goes to row 500, the numbers within any given cell may may span to 1000 and may be a mixed number such as 101.4
3. Capitalization of the words in the string does change but it doesn't seem to be working even for those that do follow the coded format e.g. "Rate variance"
Is there a way we can account for the change in capitalization? The first word in the string will be capitalized and nothing else.
4. 1 space between each word and each number, no spacing between number and colon.

Brief Recap: 
I have changed "Round Circles" to "Rate variance" and "Large Squares" to "Prior Per adj" as the numbers I want formatted.

I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you show us what you have already done? People are more likely to help you if they better understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

For a situation like this you can use Instr. What Instr does is search for a particular string in a larger string and if found, return the starting position (defined as lngPos in the example below).

Instr however does not support any 'wildcard' / LIKE searches, which is a problem given the numbers will vary in your situation. However, since we are only dealing with numbers, we can easily get around this by looping through a bunch of numbers (in the example below, we loop through numbers 1 - 100). When we find matching text the lngPos value will be greater than 0.

Also defined below is a variable called Length. This is just the character length of the string you are searching for. We need to know this, so we can format the correct number of characters.

Using this information (the starting position & the length) we can then write a with statement which will format the specified characters.

```
Sub Format_Text()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lngPos As Integer
Dim length As Integer

For Each c In Range("A1:A10")

    For i = 1 To 100
        lngPos = InStr(c.Value, "Round Circles (" & i & "):")
        length = Len("Round Circles (" & i & "):")
        If lngPos > 0 Then
            With c.Characters(Start:=lngPos, length:=length - 1).Font
                .FontStyle = "Italic"
            End With
        End If

        lngPos = InStr(c.Value, "Large Squares (" & i & "):")
        length = Len("Large Squares (" & i & "):")
        If lngPos > 0 Then
            With c.Characters(Start:=lngPos, length:=length - 1).Font
                .FontStyle = "Italic"
            End With
        End If
    Next i

Next c

End Sub
```

for your own use. Change the ***Range("A1:A10")*** to be whatever range you need it to be. Change the ***For i = 1 To 100*** to be whatever number range you are working with

If you have any questions or need help debugging, let me know

Comment: Hello Bobby, Thank you for your quick response. I seem to be having trouble getting this to work. It doesn't bug out but doesn't seem to do anything exactly which I am sure is a fault on my end. I am new to this site and I cannot seem to post my code in the comment box to show you the edits I have made such as you did above. Can you tell me how you did that?

Comment: @JackFD, alright too easy! lets troubleshoot. 1. Check the Range ("A1:A10") and make sure that is updated to your cell range. 2. how high do your numbers go? update the For i = 1 To 100 to match your requirements. 3. Instr is case specific, so check to see if capitalization is the cause. 4. what is the spacing between the word, e.g. Round Circles, and the number, e.g (8):, is it a single space, double space, or is it a tab? and is the spacing consistent? 5. Any other variation in the text we wrote in macro, vs the one in the file, lets do a double check as Instr requires exact match

Comment: @JackFD, Also Don't think you can add code in a comment to an answer, I would just edit your original question. Type your code in at the bottom then in the formatting bar, you should see something that looks like { }. highlight your code and click that button.

Comment: I have edited my original post addressing your comments and adding my code.

Answer (score 0):

The additional information you provided does change the situation. I understand sometimes information can be sensitive, but next time please try to be more explicit.

First, as you mentioned in your edited comment, you will need to convert to values for this to work.

Secondly, since we are working with decimals we need to update our loop statement.Let's define i as a double rather than an integer, that way we can work with decimals. then we need to add a step size increase to our loop. In below example I've added Step 0.01. Also because excel can be weird sometimes, I've also included a Round(i, 2) statement, this keeps the result to 2 decimal places.

Finally to allow for variance in capitalization, lets adjust our Instr with UCase to capitalize everything. don't worry this wont affect the results.

This might not be the best way to do this, as now you will be looping through 500 cells x 100,000 potential numbers, but hopefully it will get the job done.

```
Sub Italicize()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Double
Dim lngPos As Integer
Dim length As Integer


For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L7:L500")

c.Value = c.Value

    For i = 1 To 1000 Step 0.01
        lngPos = InStr(UCase(c.Value), "RATE VARIANCE (" & Round(i, 2) & "):")
        length = Len("RATE VARIANCE (" & Round(i, 2) & "):")
        If lngPos > 0 Then
            With c.Characters(Start:=lngPos, length:=length - 1).Font
                .FontStyle = "Italic"
            End With
        End If

        lngPos = InStr(UCase(c.Value), "PRIOR PER ADJ (" & Round(i, 2) & "):")
        length = Len("PRIOR PER ADJ (" & Round(i, 2) & "):")
        If lngPos > 0 Then
            With c.Characters(Start:=lngPos, length:=length - 1).Font
                .FontStyle = "Italic"
            End With
        End If
    Next i

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say I really appreciate your help on this. My projects were pushed around so haven't had time to devote my attention to this it is none the less very appreciated.